# C# Does Process.Dispose() also cleanup the StandardInput and StandardInput.BaseStream?

Tags: c#, process, dispose

Currently working with a process I am starting up and then accessing the `StandardInput.BaseStream` and then copying a `Stream` to it. Do I need to `Dispose` of the `StandardInput` and/or the `StandardInput.BaseStream` at all or is that handled with `Process.Dispose()`?

```
        Process someProgram = null;
        try
        {
            someProgram = new Process();
            someProgram.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            someProgram.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Temp\SomeProgram.exe";
            someProgram.Start();                  
            streamParamater.CopyTo(someProgram.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            someProgram.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Error Logging
        }
        finally
        {
            if (someProgram != null)
            {
                someProgram.Dispose();
            }
            streamParamater.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readers / writers and their base streams are not disposed by calling `Close()` or `Dispose()` on the `Process` instance.

The `Process.Close()` method just sets the references to null so that they can be collected by GC once there are not other references left.

There is also this comment in the [source code of `Process.Close()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,9270d03e9dfb0fb9):

```
//Don't call close on the Readers and writers
//since they might be referenced by somebody else while the 
//process is still alive but this method called.
```

So, you have to call `Dispose()` on the readers / writers if you want to make sure that the resources are freed as soon as possible.

Comment: Ahh I see that. I am now wondering if the `StandardInput.Dispose()` also disposes of `StandardInput.BaseStream`.

Comment: Looking at the source code. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,269
disposing of `StandardInput` also disposes of `StandardInput.BaseStream`. Nice.